# How to pass an array parameter in TOAD

Tags: oracle, associative-array, toad

Using toad and an oracle database, how can I call a sp and see the results by passing an array to one of the parameters of the sp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Editor tab you can call it like this:

```
begin
    myproc (my_array_type(1,4,7,9));
end;
```